# Incorrectly recognized math symbol from PDF in LaTeX

Tags: r, math, pdf, latex, pdf-generation

I am generating plot in **R** and save it as **PDF** with:

```
pdf(
  file='Plots/errors.pdf',
  height=4,
  width=7,
  onefile=TRUE,
  family='Helvetica',
  pointsize=12
)

# Here is my graphics

dev.off()
```

Somewhere inside graphics I have:

```
mtext(
  expression(mu[H1])
)
```

It produces neat **PDF** with correctly processed greek letter **µ**.

Then I import this **PDF** in **LaTeX** article with:

```
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth,height=0.4\textheight]{../Plots/errors.pdf}
```

But instead of **µ** sign of infinity (**∞**) is displayed.

Why?

Comment: What PDF reader are you using? It looks fine in Adobe Acrobat reader, but wrong like you say in Evince... I think its an encoding issue...

Comment: @Spacedman Hm, really! I am using Adobe Acrobat and TeXStudio PDF Viewer.

Comment: Do you want screenshots? If you read help(pdf) it talks about issues like this.

Comment: @Spacedman Thank you, I think `help(pdf)` will be enough. :)

Answer (score 0):

For seamless integration without the encoding issues, I would look at package 'TikzDevice'.  It outputs Tikz images in LaTeX format.  For example:

```
require(tikzDevice)


setwd("/Path/To/LaTeX/Files/")

#Names of LaTeX symbols
syms <- c('alpha', 'theta', 'tau', 'beta', 'vartheta', 'pi', 'upsilon', 'gamma', 'varpi', 'phi', 'delta', 'kappa', 'rho', 'varphi', 'epsilon', 'lambda', 'varrho', 'chi', 'varepsilon', 'mu', 'sigma', 'psi', 'zeta', 'nu', 'varsigma', 'omega', 'eta', 'xi', 'Gamma', 'Lambda', 'Sigma', 'Psi', 'Delta', 'Xi', 'Upsilon', 'Omega', 'Theta', 'Pi', 'Phi')
len <- length(syms)

# random colors (red, green, blue)
r <- round(runif(len), 2)
g <- round(runif(len), 2)
b <- round(runif(len), 2)

# calculate dummy data points
x <- runif(50,1,10)
y <- x + rnorm(length(x))
fit <- lm(y ~ x)
rsq <- summary(fit)$r.squared
rsq <- signif(rsq,4)

# plot the result, will create symbol-regression.tex in the working
# directory the first time this is run it may take a long time because the
# process of calulating string widths for proper placement is
# computationally intensive, the results will get cached for the current R
# session or will get permenantly cached if you set
# options( tikzMetricsDictionary='/path/to/dictionary' ) which will be
# created if it does not exist.  Also if the flag standAlone is not set to
# TRUE then a file is created which can be included with \include{}

tikz('symbolr.tex', width = 4,height = 4,pointsize = 12)

# The syntax is mar=c(bottom, left, top, right).
par(mar=c(2,2,2,2))
# plot the box and the regression line
plot(x, y, type='n', xlab='', ylab='')
box()
abline(fit)

# add the latex symbols as points
text(x, y, paste('\\color[rgb]{',r,',',g,',',b,'}{$\\',syms,'$}',sep=''))
# Display the correlation coefficient
mtext(paste("Linear model: $R^{2}=",rsq,"$" ),line=0.5)
# and the equation of the line
legend('bottom', legend = paste("$y = ", round(coef(fit)[2],3),'x +', round(coef(fit)[1],3), '$',  sep=''), bty= 'n')

# Close the device
dev.off()
```

Then all you have to do is include the file just output from R in your LaTeX document.